# Nuget and packages folder - CHECKED IN

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I've just noticed that I've added a package via nuget and it's marked the packages folder for checkin. When did this behaviour change?

Comment: This has been the case for a long time. Maybe you were running a really early version of NuGet

Comment: @dfowler I recall that this – add to pending checkins – was the default at least as early as 1.3.

Comment: Excellent it had been a while since I'd used it purely because of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behaviour changed around the 1.3 release. Thank dFowler, Richard